# Removing protect_from_forgery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, xss

I have a question about protect_from_forgery in Rails app.
I use Devise in my rails project, recently a security issue had been addressed concerning the version I've been using, namely 2.1.2 of Devise.
I've update from 2.1.2 to 2.1.3 and using Rails 3.2.12

So I tried to update it, but after update I keep getting a 401 and couldn't login anymore.

Now my question to the community, to make login process work again I needed to remove the protect_from_forgery from my application_controller and everything worked back fine.

But I was wondering if I by removing this didn't introduced any other security holes?
To use the app you must be logged in before you could do anything. So I assume a XSS wouldn't affect my app or does it?

Looking forward to getting some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using custom forms for login rather than using default form from devise or form generated by rails form helpers.

This kind of issue may happen in case when post request comes without authenticity token.

For custom forms you required to add authenticity token as hidden parameter.